# Get node console output to file with pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

How can I get node console output (such as errors) to a file with pm2? 
I tried to run `pm2 task --log-type json` but it didn't work

There is no log file in /var/log or in the project directory.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `pm2 list` and note process-id for which you want to see the log.

Save the executed process using `pm2 save`

Then, enter `pm2 logs process-id` to see the logs and report of respective pm2 process.

Answer (score 1):

Just add log property to your ecosystem config file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: name,
      script: './server/server.js',
      error_file: './logs/err.log',
      out_file: './logs/out.log',
      log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:SSS',
    }
  ]
}
```

Then pm2 will automate write log into these file (one for console.log and one for console.error)

Comment: It maybe permission error, if pm2 can't create logs folder, server can't start. Try to manual create logs folder in your project